# How does autoconfig/autodiscover work?

Tags: users, configuration

I have a server with OpenLDAP/Kerberos authentication with 7 desktops/clients. Manually generating a new user and configuring a new profile (gnome, evolution mail accounts, evolution calendar/tasks accounts, firefox bookmarks and preferences, etc.) is getting very tedious and time consuming.

I have read snippets about storing user configuration in OpenLDAP and automatically generating account information, but how does it work? Which packages should I read up on? I have searched high and low, but I seem to be using wrong search terms or something. Thank you for any guidance/direction :)